# Matrix inversion for a $3\times3$ matix

Tags: matrices

How does one show that a $3\times3$ matrix is invertible? 
The matrix is:
$$ \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos X & -\sin X & 0 \\
\sin X & \cos X &0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right),$$ 
invertible for all values of $X$.

Comment: If you're not interested in what the inverse actually is, it is enough to compute its determinant.

Comment: Do you know that matrix $A$ is invertible iff $\det A \neq 0$?

Answer (score 1):

*Method 1*:  Recall that $$\cos^2 X + \sin^2 X=1;$$ we can use this identity to find the inverse:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos X & -\sin X & 0 \\
\sin X & \cos X & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos X & \sin X & 0 \\
-\sin X & \cos X & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

---

*Method 2*:  The matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos X & -\sin X & 0 \\
\sin X & \cos X & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
may be thought of as a [rotation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RotationMatrix.html) by $X$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ about the $z$-axis.  So, the inverse would be rotating by $-X$, which is described by
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos (-X) & -\sin (-X) & 0 \\
\sin (-X) & \cos (-X) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos X & \sin X & 0 \\
-\sin X & \cos X & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

---

*Method 3*: If we just want to show that the matrix is invertible (and not find the inverse), we can show it has non-zero [determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant):
$$\det \begin{bmatrix}
\cos X & -\sin X & 0 \\
\sin X & \cos X & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}=\cos^2 X + \sin^2 X=1 \neq 0.$$  We can conclude that the matrix is invertible.

Comment: Thank You!! This is very useful!